Avalanche Node: 'API call rejected because chain is not done bootstrapping' error with Hardhat deployment
Problem Summary:
I'm running a local Avalanche node using AvalancheGo for development. When deploying a contract using Hardhat, I get the error: "API call rejected because chain is not done bootstrapping". Node logs repeatedly show: "bootstrapping skipped {reason: 'no provided bootstraps'}", suggesting the chains (C, P, X) aren't bootstrapped.
I've tried running the node with --network-id=local, --snow-sample-size=1, and --staking-enabled=false to bypass bootstrapping but still encounter the issue.
Question:
How can I properly configure a local Avalanche node to deploy contracts with Hardhat?
